# Network cables in attic. What riser?

Tags: ethernet

Going to sound stupid, but i have to ask. I'm running CM ethernet cable in my attic. just two runs.

I am looking for what an official 'riser' is? I've always just used eye hooks for this stuff but i wanted to see if there is a legitimate riser for the job that should be used

Comment: they have huge metal "baskets" at work, with dozens/hundreds of cable runs, but you don't need anything.

Comment: I suspect "riser" is not the word you meant, Are you attempting to ask about fasteners?  Don't use anything that crimps or pinches the cable even a little bit (I.e no staples out of a staple gun).  Also avoid hard 90 degree bends, corners/turns need to be a relaxed radius.

Answer (score 3):

Riser is more for industrial /commercial work. In a residence you can run the cable through drilled holes inside the walls. But a riser in a large building is a chase that is verticle and has fire blocks at each floor.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I understand now. i kept hearing someone talk about risers, but what they riser cable (CMR-Rated). I've been out of the loop for around 10 years so I thought maybe I had missed something somewhere.

thanks for the answer!